# Is it possible to use an instance method in a pipeline in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

Is it possible to use an instance method directly in a pipeline in F#? I am asking about the general case, but here is an example.

Say I were trying to convert a string to lowercase inside a pipeline. The `String.ToLower()` method is an instance method with signature `unit -> string`. If it were a static `string -> string` method you could use it in a pipe like this: `"MyString" |> String.ToLower`, but as it is an instance method that relies on the contents of the instance, this does not work.

I know that there are ways to work around this, such as using `"MyString" |> String.map (fun x -> Char.ToLower(x))` or defining a method `stringLower (input: string) = input.ToLower()`, but I am interested in a method for actually using the instance method directly within the pipeline.

To reiterate from above, I am not simply asking for a way to convert a string to lowercase. I am asking if there is a general way to use instance methods within a pipeline.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41317294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"MyString" |> (fun x -> x.ToLower())
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of personal opinion, but I feel that if you want to use an instance method in a pipeline, it is always more readable to just define a new variable for the result *before* the operation and then use the instance method directly. Why not just use?

```
"MyString".ToLower()
```

The above is a very simple case, but let's say your actual use case is something like this:

```
let greeting = 
  [| "hi"; "there" |]
  |> String.concat " "
  |> fun x -> x.ToUpper()
```

Here, some people prefer to write the code this way with `ToUpper` in a pipeline. I would not do this though and would just write:

```
let greetingLow = [| "hi"; "there" |] |> String.concat " "
let greeting = greetingLow.ToUpper()
```

This kind of thing often happens when the type of the thing that is being passed through the pipeline changes (e.g., from array to string here). When this happens, I find it more readable to break the pipeline.

Comment: That is a very good point. I also tend to think that excessive usage of lambdas in a pipe makes the intention less clear, which I think is a point in favor of this approach.

Comment: I have argued the same on more than one occasion, and the counter argument is then usually that it isn't idiomatic. To use another fancy word, I think it's pragmatic. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you're using some function very often, you can define them in module

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess;
  CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module String =
    let inline toUpper (s: string) = s.ToUpper()
```

And then in pipeline write

```ml
let greeting =
  [| "hi"; "there" |]
  |> String.concat " "
  |> String.toUpper
```

Cons is that you need to write thin wrappers around existing instance methods and you also need to think about overloads. But there's already libraries that define them for you (e.g. [F#+](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/35fa2a97e0c3f93c7cf36c172314e7f2d921d438/src/FSharpPlus/Extensions/String.fs#L38))

There is a [suggestion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/506) for simplified property access and method invocation in pipelines. It's *approved in principle*, but there's no even RFC yet. It would allow to write something like

```ml
  [| "hi"; "there" |]
  |> String.Join(' ', _)
  |> _.ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```